# doubling object in Python

Tags: python

how do I double the object side by side?

```
print("    *\n   * *\n  *   *\n *     *\n***   ***\n  *   *\n  *   *\n  *****" *2)
```

this code puts the objects one below another, how do i do that it prints it besides?

Comment: Manually. You would need to do something like split each piece on lines, then concatenate corresponding lines together, then print that.

Comment: It would be easier to design if you used a triple-quoted string, that way you wouldn't have to worry about placing newlines, and it's just easier visually.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
obj = "    *\n   * *\n  *   *\n *     *\n***   ***\n  *   *\n  *   *\n  *****"

lines = obj.split('\n')
space = len(max(lines, key=len)) + 3

for line in lines:
    print(line + " "* (space - len(line)) + line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a multiline string for your image, iterate through the lines and print each one doubled:

```py
# using dots to indicate spaces clearly
s = '''\
....*.....
...*.*....
..*...*...
.*.....*..
***...***.
..*...*...
..*...*...
..*****...
'''.replace('.',' ')

# double each line
for line in s.splitlines():
    print(line * 2)
```

Output:

```
    *         *     
   * *       * *    
  *   *     *   *   
 *     *   *     *  
***   *** ***   *** 
  *   *     *   *   
  *   *     *   *   
  *****     *****
```

Comment: Nice and clean :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
arrow = "    *\n   * *\n  *   *\n *     *\n***   ***\n  *   *\n  *   *\n  *****"
    
arrow_lines = arrow.split("\n")
double_arrow_lines = [line +" "*(15-len(line)) +line for line in arrow_lines]
double_arrow = "\n".join(double_arrow_lines)
    
print(double_arrow)
```

Comment: Mine is almost the same as nokla's answer, which you should validate :)